# XSLT: transform xml into dtd conform xml file with an xslt sheet

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to transform an xml file into an dtd conform xml file... therefore I have to write a xslt-sheet...
this is the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE autoren SYSTEM "autoren.dtd">
<autoren>
    <autor>
        <nachname>Prudhomme</nachname>
        <vorname>Sully</vorname>
        <nobelpreis>1901</nobelpreis>
        <sprache>französisch</sprache>
        <buch>
            <titel>t1888</titel>
            <erscheinungsjahr>1888</erscheinungsjahr>
        </buch>
    </autor>

    <autor>
        <nachname>Hauptmann</nachname>
        <vorname>Gerhard</vorname>
        <nobelpreis>1912</nobelpreis>
        <sprache>deutsch</sprache>
        <buch>
            <titel>t1900</titel>
            <erscheinungsjahr>1900</erscheinungsjahr>
        </buch>
        <buch>
            <titel>t1901</titel>
            <erscheinungsjahr>1901</erscheinungsjahr>
        </buch>
    </autor>

    <autor>
        <nachname>France</nachname>
        <vorname>Anatol</vorname>
        <nobelpreis>1921</nobelpreis>
        <sprache>französisch</sprache>
        <buch>
            <titel>t1900</titel>
            <erscheinungsjahr>1900</erscheinungsjahr>
        </buch>
    </autor>

    <autor>
        <nachname>Lagerlöf</nachname>
        <vorname>Selma</vorname>
        <nobelpreis>1909</nobelpreis>
        <sprache>schwedisch</sprache>
        <buch>
            <titel>t1900</titel>
            <erscheinungsjahr>1900</erscheinungsjahr>
        </buch>
    </autor>

    <autor>
        <nachname>Hemingway</nachname>
        <vorname>Ernest</vorname>
        <nobelpreis>1954</nobelpreis>
        <sprache>englisch</sprache>
        <buch>
            <titel>t1965</titel>
            <erscheinungsjahr>1965</erscheinungsjahr>
        </buch>
        <buch>
            <titel>t1951</titel>
            <erscheinungsjahr>1951</erscheinungsjahr>
        </buch>
    </autor>

    <autor>
        <nachname>Cornwell</nachname>
        <vorname>Patricia</vorname>
        <sprache>englisch</sprache>
        <buch>
            <titel>From Potter's Field</titel>
            <erscheinungsjahr>1995</erscheinungsjahr>
        </buch>
        <buch>
            <titel>t1995</titel>
            <erscheinungsjahr>1995</erscheinungsjahr>
        </buch>
    </autor>

    <autor>
        <nachname>Böll</nachname>
        <vorname>Heinrich</vorname>
        <nobelpreis>1972</nobelpreis>
        <sprache>deutsch</sprache>
        <buch>
            <titel>t1969</titel>
            <erscheinungsjahr>1969</erscheinungsjahr>
        </buch>
        <buch>
            <titel>t1965</titel>
            <erscheinungsjahr>1965</erscheinungsjahr>
        </buch>
    </autor>

    <autor>
        <nachname>Gide</nachname>
        <vorname>André</vorname>
        <nobelpreis>1947</nobelpreis>
        <sprache>französisch</sprache>
        <buch>
            <titel>t1945</titel>
            <erscheinungsjahr>1945</erscheinungsjahr>
        </buch>
    </autor>

    <autor>
        <nachname>Mann</nachname>
        <vorname>Thomas</vorname>
        <nobelpreis>1929</nobelpreis>
        <sprache>deutsch</sprache>
        <buch>
            <titel>t1930</titel>
            <erscheinungsjahr>1930</erscheinungsjahr>
        </buch>
        <buch>
            <titel>t1910</titel>
            <erscheinungsjahr>1910</erscheinungsjahr>
        </buch>
    </autor>

    <autor>
        <nachname>Mann</nachname>
        <vorname>Heinrich</vorname>
        <sprache>deutsch</sprache>
        <buch>
            <titel>t1920</titel>
            <erscheinungsjahr>1920</erscheinungsjahr>
        </buch>
    </autor>

    <autor>
        <nachname>Faulkner</nachname>
        <vorname>William</vorname>
        <nobelpreis>1949</nobelpreis>
        <sprache>englisch</sprache>
        <buch>
            <titel>t1930</titel>
            <erscheinungsjahr>1930</erscheinungsjahr>
        </buch>
        <buch>
            <titel>t1932</titel>
            <erscheinungsjahr>1932</erscheinungsjahr>
        </buch>
    </autor>

</autoren>
```

this is my .dtd form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<!ELEMENT bücher (buch*)>

<!ELEMENT buch (titel, erscheinungsjahr, autor)>
<!ATTLIST buch sprache CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT autor (nachname, vorname)>
<!ATTLIST autor nobelpreis CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT vorname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT nachname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT titel (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT erscheinungsjahr (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT nobelpreis (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT sprache (#PCDATA)>
```

what I did for now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes" method="xml" />


    <xsl:template match="autoren">      
        <bücher>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="autor">                
                <xsl:sort select="erscheinungsjahr" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:sort select="nachname"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </bücher>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="autor">
        <buch>
        <Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="nachname"/> 
        </Name>
        <Vorname>
            <xsl:value-of select="vorname"/>
        </Vorname>
            <JahrNobelpreis>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="nobelpreis" />
            </JahrNobelpreis>
        </buch>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

has anybody an idea how to realise this?

Comment: See my solution below. It's a strange target DTD, though. Why make a year an attribute in one case and a tag in the other case? Actually, it makes more sense the other way round since the `<erscheinungsjahr>` (publishing date) can only occur once but an author can possibly have several Nobel prizes in different years which would speak for using a tag.

Comment: Is this the output you were expecting?

Comment: Any feedback on my solution?

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT does the required conversion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes" method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="autoren">      
    <bücher>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="autor/buch">
        <xsl:sort select="erscheinungsjahr" order="ascending" data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:sort select="../nachname"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </bücher>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="buch">
    <buch>
      <xsl:attribute name="sprache">
        <xsl:value-of select="../sprache"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <titel><xsl:value-of select="titel"></xsl:value-of></titel>
      <erscheinungsjahr><xsl:value-of select="erscheinungsjahr"></xsl:value-of></erscheinungsjahr>
      <autor>
        <xsl:attribute name="nobelpreis">
          <xsl:value-of select="../nobelpreis"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <nachname><xsl:value-of select="../nachname"/></nachname>
        <vorname><xsl:value-of select="../vorname"/></vorname>
      </autor>
    </buch>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to produce this output which should be in alignment with the DTD mentioned above

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<bücher>
  <buch sprache="französisch">
    <titel>t1888</titel>
    <erscheinungsjahr>1888</erscheinungsjahr>
    <autor nobelpreis="1901">
      <nachname>Prudhomme</nachname>
      <vorname>Sully</vorname>
    </autor>
  </buch>
  <buch sprache="französisch">
    <titel>t1900</titel>
    <erscheinungsjahr>1900</erscheinungsjahr>
    <autor nobelpreis="1921">
      <nachname>France</nachname>
      <vorname>Anatol</vorname>
    </autor>
  </buch>
  <buch sprache="deutsch">
    <titel>t1900</titel>
    <erscheinungsjahr>1900</erscheinungsjahr>
    <autor nobelpreis="1912">
      <nachname>Hauptmann</nachname>
      <vorname>Gerhard</vorname>
    </autor>
  </buch>
  <buch sprache="schwedisch">
    <titel>t1900</titel>
    <erscheinungsjahr>1900</erscheinungsjahr>
    <autor nobelpreis="1909">
      <nachname>Lagerlöf</nachname>
      <vorname>Selma</vorname>
    </autor>
  </buch>
  <buch sprache="deutsch">
    <titel>t1901</titel>
    <erscheinungsjahr>1901</erscheinungsjahr>
    <autor nobelpreis="1912">
      <nachname>Hauptmann</nachname>
      <vorname>Gerhard</vorname>
    </autor>
  </buch>
  <buch sprache="deutsch">
    <titel>t1910</titel>
    <erscheinungsjahr>1910</erscheinungsjahr>
    <autor nobelpreis="1929">
      <nachname>Mann</nachname>
      <vorname>Thomas</vorname>
    </autor>
  </buch>
  <buch sprache="deutsch">
    <titel>t1920</titel>
    <erscheinungsjahr>1920</erscheinungsjahr>
    <autor nobelpreis="">
      <nachname>Mann</nachname>
      <vorname>Heinrich</vorname>
    </autor>
  </buch>
  <buch sprache="englisch">
    <titel>t1930</titel>
    <erscheinungsjahr>1930</erscheinungsjahr>
    <autor nobelpreis="1949">
      <nachname>Faulkner</nachname>
      <vorname>William</vorname>
    </autor>
  </buch>
  <buch sprache="deutsch">
    <titel>t1930</titel>
    <erscheinungsjahr>1930</erscheinungsjahr>
    <autor nobelpreis="1929">
      <nachname>Mann</nachname>
      <vorname>Thomas</vorname>
    </autor>
  </buch>
  <buch sprache="englisch">
    <titel>t1932</titel>
    <erscheinungsjahr>1932</erscheinungsjahr>
    <autor nobelpreis="1949">
      <nachname>Faulkner</nachname>
      <vorname>William</vorname>
    </autor>
  </buch>
  <buch sprache="französisch">
    <titel>t1945</titel>
    <erscheinungsjahr>1945</erscheinungsjahr>
    <autor nobelpreis="1947">
      <nachname>Gide</nachname>
      <vorname>André</vorname>
    </autor>
  </buch>
  <buch sprache="englisch">
    <titel>t1951</titel>
    <erscheinungsjahr>1951</erscheinungsjahr>
    <autor nobelpreis="1954">
      <nachname>Hemingway</nachname>
      <vorname>Ernest</vorname>
    </autor>
  </buch>
  <buch sprache="deutsch">
    <titel>t1965</titel>
    <erscheinungsjahr>1965</erscheinungsjahr>
    <autor nobelpreis="1972">
      <nachname>Böll</nachname>
      <vorname>Heinrich</vorname>
    </autor>
  </buch>
  <buch sprache="englisch">
    <titel>t1965</titel>
    <erscheinungsjahr>1965</erscheinungsjahr>
    <autor nobelpreis="1954">
      <nachname>Hemingway</nachname>
      <vorname>Ernest</vorname>
    </autor>
  </buch>
  <buch sprache="deutsch">
    <titel>t1969</titel>
    <erscheinungsjahr>1969</erscheinungsjahr>
    <autor nobelpreis="1972">
      <nachname>Böll</nachname>
      <vorname>Heinrich</vorname>
    </autor>
  </buch>
  <buch sprache="englisch">
    <titel>From Potter's Field</titel>
    <erscheinungsjahr>1995</erscheinungsjahr>
    <autor nobelpreis="">
      <nachname>Cornwell</nachname>
      <vorname>Patricia</vorname>
    </autor>
  </buch>
  <buch sprache="englisch">
    <titel>t1995</titel>
    <erscheinungsjahr>1995</erscheinungsjahr>
    <autor nobelpreis="">
      <nachname>Cornwell</nachname>
      <vorname>Patricia</vorname>
    </autor>
  </buch>
</bücher>
```

Comment: @user2774480: Could you give some feedback if my solution works or not? Thanks!